# Excel addin for QTP - Available/Workaround?

Tags: excel, vba, automation, qtp

When using object spy in QTP 11 for Excel the whole workbook is recognized as 1 object and the clicks are simulated by X,Y co-ordinates.
I was facing a similar problem with Flex based application, I used the Flex addin after which I was able to spy inside the flash object.

Is there a similar addin which can allow us to spy inside the workbook?
Actually I have a few buttons inside the workbooks which I am able to click by passing the X,Y cordinates right now, I want to click them by providing the object ids.

Any help/suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you want to manipulate a workbook, you don´t (and should not) go via Excel´s GUI. Use the automation object instead.

Comment: My workbook is basically a tool, which has buttons to which some macros are assigned, clicking on those buttons fetches some data from DB.

Comment: You could address those buttons etc, too

Comment: Through Virtual objects??

Comment: No, through Excel's automation object. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx. It also exposes what's on your sheets, including buttons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out QTP's [virtual objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_virtual_objects.htm) this may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to capture virtual objects, But I am getting an error "Failed to create Virtual Object Definition" Any ideas? QTP: v11